# IBM Watson Studio: Data icon not showing in Cognos Dashboard

Tags: ibm-watson, dashboard, cognos, watson-studio

I've downloaded the Data files into data Assets
But, when I open an embedded cognos dashboard, there is no data icon in the upper left-hand corner. So I cannot start the dashboard because there is no data.
[Dashboard missing data icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIULf.png)
And, I can not click on the add data source icon. Any help would be appreciated!

Every video I see about the embedded cognos dashboard show this icon or a similar one:[Data icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LaBRI.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because the data icon is getting hidden under the  horizontal announcement bar. If you x that announcement , you should be able to see the

[image]